# Is code after catch block is bad or meaningless?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am asking a simple question. Is it bad to have any code after catch block. i.e. do we need to include them inside the try and re-throw a wrapper exception inside catch instead?

I am not asking about finally operations.

Lets take an example. In here doSomething() method throws an exception called 'SomeException'.

code1:

```
try{
 doSomething();   
}catch(SomeException e){
  throw new AnotherException(e);
}
doAnotherThing();
return someResult;
```

code2:

```
try{
   doSomething(); 
   doAnotherThing(); 
   return someResult; 
}catch(SomeException e){
   throw new AnotherException(e);
}
```

In above 2 examples, Are there any plus points in code2?

Comment: @DaveNewton can you please elaborate as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a differece between the 2 cases if `doSomething()` doesn't thow an exception, but `doAnotherThing()` throws `SomeException`.

1. `SomeException` will be propated further on in the code.
2. `SomeException` will be caught by the catch block and re-thrown as `AnotherException` further on.

Another case to consider is when the catch block doesn't re-throw the exception.

1. will execute `doAnotherThing()`
2. will not.

So, as it was already stated in other answers, having 1 try-catch block per line makes your code clearer and avoids unexpected behavior. On the other hand I would consider grouping multiple lines in the same block when you have something like this

```
try {
   doSomething(); // can throw SomeException 
   doAnotherThing(); 
   doSomething(); // can throw SomeException as well  
   return someResult; 
} catch(SomeException e) {
   throw new AnotherException(e);
}
```

This makes sens if we don't care whether it is the first or the second call to `doSomething()` that threw exception and we don't care if `doAnotherThing()` was called or not.

Answer (score 1):

Judgments about "bad" feel subjective to me.

My preference is one try/catch per method, with all code in the try.

The compiler doesn't stop you from putting code after the catch.  I would cite you in a code review.

Comment: what are the reasons for your preference? :)

Comment: Personal taste, readability, look of the source, clean code, the notion of a method doing one thing well.  When I see code tossed around inside a method, it feels disorganized and muddy.  I'd refactor the try/catch block into a single method call.  I might take that mess you thrust after the catch block and make that a method, too.  It's sloppy.

Comment: I used to work for a jet engine manufacturer as a mechanical engineer.  Must be my roots coming out.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with style 2 where you put more code in the try block is that it can unexpectedly catch an exception that you weren't expecting there, especially when it's a rather high-level exception or a runtime exception. Say you're trying to convert a string to a number and are catching the possible NumberFormatException. So assuming style 2, you execute more code after that with DoAnotherThing. Maybe you're even calling a library. Now this library throws the same exception but you're handling it like it was coming from your own code.

For that reason I prefer small try/catch blocks unless I'm really sure about the rest of the code that is following. But of course it depends a lot on the exception you are actually catching (a custom one from a library you're calling there obviously won't be thrown elsewhere) and on readability of the code, etc. etc.